# AngularJS $http request issue in HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, https, cross-domain

I have a problem in my angularjs $http request. When I send request to the API it was blocked by the browser like:
ERROR IN FIREFOX : Blocked loading mixed active content “http://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token/”

ERROR IN CHROME: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/load.shtml#/register/pos/docs/2323232221555/new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

How can I fixed this problem? Any idea is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: hit your web API endpoints using SSL.

https://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token/

Comment: What response are you getting back from the server?

Comment: Blocked loading mixed active content “http://www.example.com/rest/default/V1/integration/admin/token”

Comment: Hit the endpoint with a client like Postman, please. What status code is returned? Is that server set up for HTTPS?

Comment: In POSTMAN it is working but when I use it in my code its block

Comment: the server made the request is HTTPS but the API is HTTP

Comment: The endpoint in my answer: when you hit it, what's the status code returned? It might expedite everything if you update your question with relevant HTML and JS.

Comment: If you look at the network activity from dev tools, you'll see some requests are https while others are http, this is the reason for the error. You have to make sure it's all https in order to it to work. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: Update your requests to use HTTPS, make sure they are all returning success codes - not 404s. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: the API link is only in HTTP

Comment: Then you won't be able to use it securely on your HTTPS site.

Comment: so there no other way to make a request from HTTPS to HTTP?

Comment: You could fetch your HTTP API data server side, and then expose that data through an HTTPS endpoint of your own.